# problemas al ejecutar eventos javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, web, aplicación-web

Me he dado con la misma piedra muchas veces, cada vez que implemento un capturador de eventos se ejecuta el primero y solo el primero, los demás botones con eventos no logran hacer nada. Todo lo que quiero hacer es cargar elementos div y p desde el archivo elementos.php en la pagina index.php, que seria una pagina web dinámica, es decir algunos elementos estáticos y solo los div loader1, loader2 y loader3 cambien el contenido.

He utilizado

```
   document.getElementById("registro").addEventListener("click", cargar_registro_usuario);
 document.getElementById("registro-final").addEventListener("click", cargar_registro_usuario_final);
```

Las funciones

```
    
  function cargar_registro_usuario(){
    $("#loader1").load('elementos.php #registro-usuario');
  }

  function cargar_registro_usuario_final(){
    $("#loader1").load('elementos.php #pedidos');
  }
```

y también he utilizado

```
     $('#registro').on('click', function() {
    $("#loader1").load('elementos.php #registro-usuario');
```

También intente

```
    function cargar_registro_usuario(){
    $("#loader1").load('elementos.php #registro-usuario');
    console.log(e);
  };
  document.getElementById("#registro"),onclick=function(){
    cargar_registro_usuario();
  }
```

El botón

```
<input type="button" id="registro" name="registro" value="Registrarse" onclick='argar_registro_usuario'>
```

Pero es aun peor ya que sin importar el botón que presione me enviara a la vista de registro, cuando es algo que solo debería suceder al presionar el botón registro.
Y con cada código es lo mismo no paso del primer evento capturado.

EDIT-------

Este es el codigo html de la pagina index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.ripples/0.5.3/jquery.ripples.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="container-top">
    <header>
        <p class="titulo">Liquid Health</p>
    </header>
 
    <main class="container">
        <div id="loader1">
            <p id="titulo-loader1"></p>
                <p class="titulo-usuario">Registro/Inicio de sesión</p>
                
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="Usuario" placeholder="Usuario/Email">
                  <input type="password" id="password" name="Contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña">
                  <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Login" value="Ingresar">
                  <input type="button" id="registro" name="registro" value="Registrarse" onclick='asd'>
                  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                  <label">¿Quieres ser nuestro cliente?<Input type="button" id="posible-cliente" name="posible-cliente" value="Click Aquí">
              
        </div>

        <div id="loader2"></div>

        <div id="loader3"></div>
        
   </main>
    <footer >
        <section id="logos">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/campaign/landing.php?campaign_id=1742494936&extra_1=s%7Cc%7C339385163690%7Ce%7Cfacebook%27%7C&placement=&creative=339385163690&keyword=facebook%27&partner_id=googlesem&extra_2=campaignid%3D1742494936%26adgroupid%3D65025591501%26matchtype%3De%26network%3Dg%26source%3Dnotmobile%26search_or_content%3Ds%26device%3Dc%26devicemodel%3D%26adposition%3D%26target%3D%26targetid%3Dkwd-362360550869%26loc_physical_ms%3D1003325%26loc_interest_ms%3D%26feeditemid%3D%26param1%3D%26param2%3D&gclid=CjwKCAiAqIKNBhAIEiwAu_ZLDvwG5wExbUraiprn-uJEGJw9dQf866jAsnKkbWkH0bt-TwbWHEZORhoCIQAQAvD_BwE"><img src="img/facebook.png" height="100%" width="25%"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="img/instagram.png" height="100%" width="25%"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=es"><img src="img/twitter.png" height="100%" width="25%"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </section>
        
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT2-------------------------

Quiero utilizar

```
const contenedor_elementos = document.querySelector('elementos.php #contenedor-elementos')
```

pero al parecer no toma en cuenta #contenedor-elementos pero si lo dejo solo con elementos.php carga todo el contenido del archivo elementos.php, entonces supongo que el error en el código es de sintaxis entre los paréntesis del querySelector.

Estos son 2 de los elementos contenidos por el archivo elementos.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor-elementos">
        
    <div id="registro_cliente">
               <p class="titulo-usuario">Registro</p>
               <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
               <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Usuario/Email" required>
               <input type="password" id="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
               <input type="password" id="comprobar-password" name="comprobar-contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
               <input type="text" id="nombre-empresa" name="nombre-empresa" placeholder="Nombre de la empresa" required >
               <input type="text" id="direccion-empresa" name="direccion-empresa" placeholder="Dirección con Google Maps">
               <input type="submit" id="registro-final-cliente" name="registro-final-cliente" value="Registro" >
            </div >
<!REGISTRO DE NUEVO USUARIO- listo>
            <div id="registro_usuario">
                
                <p class="titulo-usuario">Registro de usuario</p>
               <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
               <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Usuario/Email" required>
               <input type="password" id="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
               <input type="password" id="comprobar-password" name="comprobar-contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
               <input type="button" id="registro-final" name="registro-final" value="Registro" >
                
            
            </div >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Todos los botones tienen el mismo `id`?

Comment: Trata de ver si tus errores entran dentros de los más comunes mencionados acá: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp#:~:text=When%20executing%20JavaScript%20code%2C%20different%20errors%20can%20occur.,due%20to%20wrong%20input%2C%20and%20other%20unforeseeable%20things.

Comment: No, cada botón tiene su propio id

Comment: ¿Porqué usas un `input` de tipo `submit` si no tienes un elemento `form`? Para acciones de botones con [tag:javascript], si no usas un formulario, [es preferible usar un `input` de tipo `button` o directamente un elemento `button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit#using_submit_buttons). Eso en principio. Por otro lado, en el código JS que enlazas, tienes `'argar_...'`, te falta una letra en el nombre del método. Además tienes un error en el código `html` que muestras. El último elemento `input` lo declaras con `I` mayúscula, debe ser minúscula. Saludos

Comment: solucione esos errores pero los problemas persisten.